# Play! Framework - creating simple html links

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a website that I have made using several HTML files and one CSS file. I am currently attempting to switch over to the Play! Scala Framework. For some reason I am having a really hard time figuring out how to link one html page to another.

Right now all my html files are saved in the 'views' folder with names such as "index.scala.html", "aboutpage.scala.html" and so on. In simple HTML, to create a button link to a new page it looks something like this:

```
        <form action="index.html" method="get">
            <button class="navlink">Home</button>
        </form> 
        <form action="aboutpage.html" method="get">
            <button class="navlink">About Us</button>
        </form>
        <form action="publications.html" method="get">
            <button class="navlink">Publications</button>
        </form>
```

This does not work on Play! obviously, I think I may need to work with the Application and controllers files. How do you go about creating different pages in your website through Play!?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Check out the documentation for [Reverse Routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting):

Assuming you have a route like this:

```
GET   /about          controllers.Application.about()
```

You can change your HTML to this:

```
<form action="@routes.Application.about()" method="get">
```

Comment: Hey @Todd thanks for your quick reply.

If my current Application file looks  a little like this:
        public static Result index() {
     
        return ok(index.render("APP IS READY"));
    }
    
    public static Result uploadSuccess(){
     
      return ok("Got request " + request() + "!");
    }

How should I create the about() method? I tried a simple one that looks similar to the index() method, but I am still confused on how to link it to the aboutPage.scala.html view. I dont need the URI to be dynamic either. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cazs A key point to realize is that your *.scala.html source files are not really to be thought of as user-visible paths on your webserver, like in the old days. They're just templates that generate HTML data. They need not be named the same as the routes. And the controller for a route might use 0 templates or many, depending on what you're doing. Routes define your application's URLs and reverse-routing is how you can generate those URLs for use as links, form actions, etc. It's a beautiful thing, because it let's you rely on the compiler to keep your internal linking is stable.