# Build URL/Page links with Scala in Play Framework - clicking to open a new page

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala and am trying to build an href link to another page within a website that was already built with HTML and JavaScript.  All the links are set up as:

```
<a href="mypage.html">
```

I have been researching Scala and understand that it is more routing and configuration than just referring to a another page.  I also understand that the other html pages seem to be used as a Single Page Application setup using the @content tag in the main.scala.html page.  I may be wrong on this description, but this is how it makes sense to me.

I have set up a new Scala page and am referencing it in my HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ss-12 margbot30">
<a class="services_item" href="@views.html.login3(loginForm)">
<p>
<b>New</b> User Account
</p> <span>Sign up for a user account</span>
</a>
</div>
```

It does not give me an error, but actually show that login3.scala.html page in that `<div>` tag.  I wanted to have the text clicked and then open that page.

How do I get this link or route to work correctly?

I found this post, but I am still not sure what to do:
[Play! Framework - creating simple html links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035049/play-framework-creating-simple-html-links)

I appreciate the help and any code examples.

Answer (score 3):

What `"@views.html.login3(loginForm)"` is doing is invoking the Scala function `login3` and the resulting content is being rendered into the page.

Instead of thinking of pages linking to pages, think of pages linking to controllers.

If you have a controller like this:

```
package controllers;

class FooController extends Controller {

  def foo = Action { request =>
    Ok(views.html.foo())
  }

  def bar = Action { request =>
    Ok(views.html.bar())
  }
}
```

This is exposed via the routes file as

```
GET  /foo   controllers.FooController.foo
POST /bar   controllers.FooController.bar
```

In your views, you then define your hyperlinks using the generated routing:

```
<a href="@routes.FooController.foo()">whatever</a>
```

So in your case, instead of using

```
<a class="services_item" href="@views.html.login3(loginForm)">
```

you would instead have

```
<a class="services_item" href="@routes.SomeController.theFunctionThatRendersLogin3()">
```